# Return result only if there are 10 rows or more

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
select AVG(tickets_number)
from TABLE_ONE
where ofd_id = :ofdId and launch_id in
(select id from TABLE_TWO where is_actual = 1 and is_matching_completed = 1)
```

But I need to calculate average value only if there are at least 10 rows from this query, otherwise I have to return NULL.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this case expression.

```sql
select CASE WHEN COUNT(tickets_number) >= 10
            THEN AVG(tickets_number)
            ELSE NULL END average
from TABLE_ONE ...
```